# What is a difference between contribute_to_class and contribute_to_related_class?

Tags: django

I have been using `Field.contribute_to_class` method for dynamically registering fields to models.

It was not until the situation where I needed to dynamically add `ForeignKey` field that I got confused which one to use among 2 methods, `contribute_to_class(cls, name)` and `contribute_to_related_class(cls, related)`.

I've tried to find a reference but I can't see any documentations on these methods even in [django official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-api-reference).

What is difference between these two methods and what is the exact semantic of `contribute_to_related_class`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets suppose you have the following model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.MyForeignKey(User)
```

In this case `MyForeignKey.contribute_to_class()` will contribute methods/properties into the `Article` class while `MyForeignKey.contribute_to_related_class()` will do the same with the `User` class.

For example the `User.article_set` property is introduced by the ForeignKey's `contribute_to_related_class()` method.

Comment: So does that mean `MyForeignKey.contribute_to_related_class()` adds related field `article_set` to `User`?

Comment: Yes.  I added exactly the same example to my answer :-)

Comment: Can you explain each arguments of `contribute_to_related_class(cls, related)`? What kind of objects should I pass to `cls` and `related`?

Comment: You shouldn't pass anything to this function. It is called automatically by django when application is started. `cls` is an "parent class" `Article`. `related` is a special object which contains the data about the relation.

Comment: It should be noted that both of these methods are internal APIs and subject to change at any time. You should not use them unless you know that you _need_ them - something you don't know until you've figured out the internals.